# EmberJS - Filtering array removes template auto binding

Tags: ember.js

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbERr/6/)

Before applying filter to an array auto binding works perfect. But after add filter function to the array, template is not automatically refreshing.

To test this.

```
App.FieldRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {

      //scenario 1
      //controller.set('model', App.Fields);

      //scenario 2
      controller.set('model', App.Fields.filter(function(item, index, enumerable) {
        if(item.id === model.id) return true;
    }));
  }
});
```

Run jsFiddle with scenario 1(comment scenario 2 and uncomment scenario 1) then click "Gender" then click "add" button which will add an item to the array and it'll immediately reflect in the UI.

Run jsFiddle again with scenario 2. Template won't refresh automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario 1 works when you are setting the App.Fields to the content since the content holds the same memory reference of the App.Fields array. Hence push or pop on the array is reflected to the content. But your filtering operation (in setupController) is done only once when you entered the route.

You can have your filtering model in your controller

```
  controller.setProperties({'model': App.Fields, filteringModel: model});
```

and then filter your content

```
App.FieldController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
   displayArray: function(){
        return this.get('content').filterProperty('id',this.get('filteringModel.id'));
    }.property('content.@each','filteringModel') 
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbERr/9/)

Comment: when you switch between "Gender" and "Marital Status" values are not changing.

Comment: The computed property should also observe the 'filteringModel'...http://jsfiddle.net/dbERr/9/

Comment: @SelvaG it works. update your answer to that fiddle. I'll accept this.

Comment: @SelvaG do you know how to update key and desc while user types?

Comment: Have a look at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html . Meanwhile i cant get where you got stuck exactly. Can you explain it further?

Comment: Ember api guides will help you get started http://emberjs.com/api/ ... Track the ember commits in the github...Also Follow some great guys in emberjs to be updated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33988/discussion-between-user10-and-selva-g)